# configure gwibber for twitter

Tags: gwibber

I wanted to use gwibber for both facebook as well as for twitter. While I have configured properly for facebook, I am unable to do so for twitter. After giving add account, selecting twitter and authorizing, the following page opens (which is blank) and then nothing.
[image: Gwibber screenshot for twitter]
How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `gwibber-service-twitter` package:

```
sudo apt-get install gwibber-service-twitter
```

Comment: Didn't work. Probably, the services were already installed. However, I still executed the above commands and then once again tried to configure gwibber for twitter and once again the same blank screen was staring at me.